# I can't uninstall Git

Tags: macos, git, osx-lion, uninstallation

I tried to update my git version on Mac OS X 10.7, but it doesn't change the version.
It's still on 2.0.

If I run,

```
rm -rf /usr/local/git
rm /etc/paths.d/git
rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

the new version gets uninstalled, but the old one is still there (`git` is still a valid command).

How can I find the directory where this "ghost" version is installed?

Comment: For others reading this, if you are using something like Homebrew to add a new version of git don't forget to restart your terminal. You won't see the updated version until you restart the terminal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To see where git is installed:

```
which git
```

See for instance those guides:

- "[Beginner's Setup Guide for Git & Github on Mac OS X](http://burnedpixel.com/blog/setting-up-git-and-github-on-your-mac/)"
- "[Install and Update to latest version Git on Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-update-latest-version-git-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/)"

The location usually is:

```
/usr/local/git/bin/git
```

---

As mentioned in "[Can't seem to uninstall git](https://superuser.com/a/353301/141)":

`/opt/local/bin` is the location of software installed by macports, so you'll want to run this:

```
sudo port uninstall git
```

---

If you see /usr/local/bin/git, that is likely a brew installation: see "[Can't use homebrew installed git](https://superuser.com/a/777227/141)":

```
brew uninstall git
# make sure everything is alright, maybe brew will give you some hint
brew doctor
brew update  
brew install git
# magic happen, brew will give you hint /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
# and recommend you run following command
brew doctor
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: It's not there. like I said no matter what version I install and clean using the above commands there always is a Git 2.0.4 somewhere installed in my machine. That I can't find the location of the installation.

Comment: @lazev what does the which git return?

Comment: /opt/local/bin/git Those are the files that are in there.
/opt/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
/opt/local/bin/git-cvsserver
/opt/local/bin/git-receive-pack 
/opt/local/bin/git-shell
/opt/local/bin/git-upload-archive
/opt/local/bin/git-upload-pack and /opt/local/bin/gitk

Comment: @lazev do you have brew installed? See my edited answer.

Comment: I'm installing it - I let you know then in the end of the day. Many thanks.

Comment: quite strange - could remove the 2.0 version but then when I do git version I get - git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)... How many gits are here?

Comment: I found it where it is it's on - /usr/bin/git. the files there are - git   git-shell  gitk
git-cvsserver  git-upload-archive
git-receive-pack git-upload-pack
do I remove them?

Comment: @lazev yes, you can remove them, but read the answers at http://superuser.com/a/454774/141

Comment: ok, got it with brew, "chowning" every directory that I got the message that it could not be modified and I couldn't do brew link git. Also doing the rm's that brew advised. Now it's working thanks VonC for the tips. The version 1.7 is still there but mac goes first to this one.