# Git stopped working on Android studio

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio, github-for-mac

I had everything set up on Android Studio but recently it stopped working. The last time I pushed onto Git was as recent as five days ago!

When I press VCS->Enable Version Control Integration: I get a dialog box on the right corner saying:

```
Can't start Git: /usr/local/bin/git 
Probably the path to git executable is not valid: Fix it
```

When I press "`fix it`" it takes me to preferences, I tried testing the connection but, it said no such file or directory!
So I looked at the directories and there wasn't a "`git`" file in the location, when I searched further I found a "`git`" file in "`/usr/local/git`"! So I changed it to that location in preferences, to which I got another dialog box saying:

```
Cannot run program "/usr/local/git": error=13, Permission denied
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, `/usr/local/git/` is a folder.

In the preferences, you should put `/usr/local/git/bin/git`

Comment: If it is still not working, you can check out how to uninstall/reinstall Git on your Mac: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27667302/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27330167/6309

Answer (score 3):

In my case this problem happened because I updated my Xcode and I had to agree the license.

So the solutions for me was go to terminal and type:

```
sudo /usr/bin/git
```

and type '**agree**' to the terms of the software license agreements.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had to do both:
sudo /usr/bin/git AND
figure out that git was installed in /usr/local/git/current/bin/git